# How to score detector

Tags: statistical-significance, classification

I'm developing a classifier system to detect objects of interest in images. I want to report a score, but I'm a bit lost as to what the most fair and informative number is.

Sensitivity and specificity seem to be commonly used, but while I have numbers for true positive, false positives and false negatives, I'm not sure how to properly calculate 'true negative'.

Comment: Normally we use mAP, and for more information please refer to this blog post: https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173

Answer (score 0):

You should be presenting your system with a number of scenes that either contain objects of interest or do not contain such objects (e.g. 10 of each). In this situation a 'true negative' is where your system correctly fails to respond when it is presented with a scene containing no objects of interest, a  'correct rejection'.  The system could be set up to respond 'not containing objects' in this case -this would also be a correct rejection.

If you present 10 images without objects of interest and 10 containing objects of interest your classifier might identify:

8 scenes containing objects of interest as 'containing objects' (8
   hits),
2 scenes containing objects of interest, as 'not containing
   objects' (2 misses),
4 scenes not containing objects of interest as
   'containing objects of interest' (4 false alarms),
6 scenes not
   containing objects as 'not containing objects of interest' (6 correct
   rejections).

Comment: ok, but if I randomly choose regions they are very unlikely to contain either 0 or 1 object, most likely they will have several, some only partly in the image. It seems like I would need to curate a test set, and this seems artificial compared to the real use case where the system is given a large image and returns a list of objects and positions.

Comment: Hi - sounds like you are interested in an 'unsupervised' classification procedure - i.e. you don't have a test set or 'training set'?  Some more detail on your problem might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: neither sensitivity or specificity are that good measures on their own.  You'd probably want a d-prime measure which considers both.   Even if in your case you are primarily interested in a system that can correctly identify the presence of an object in a scene   (e.g. correctly identifiying the presence of markers for cancer in an xray) rather than a system with high specificity (e.g. a systme that can correctly say there are no markers for cancer present) - d prime will still be a more useful measure, and practical importance of correctly spotting objects vs correctly spotting an absence of objects can be factored into this with weighting